# Laravel Dusk won't fire Bootstrap modal through option select

Tags: jquery, laravel, bootstrap-4, bootstrap-modal, laravel-dusk

I have a Blade form with a Select control, where the last option is "Add new element", like this:

```
<div class="form-group row">
    <label for="nationality_id" class="col col-form-label">Nationality <p class="alert-danger">{{ $errors->first('nationality_id') }}</p></label>
    <select class="col form-control @error('nationality_id') is-invalid @enderror" name="nationality_id" id="nationality_id" data-toggle="tooltip">
        <option value {{ is_null(old('nationality_id', $general->nationality_id)) ? 'selected' : '' }} disabled>Select one option...</option>
        @foreach (App\Nationality::all()->sortBy('name') as $nationality)
            <option value="{{ $nationality->id }}"  {{ old('nationality_id', $general->nationality_id) == $nationality->id ? 'selected' : '' }}>{{ $nationality->nombre }}</option>
        @endforeach
        <option value="new">Add new element</option>
    </select>
</div>
```

There's a jQuery script that opens up the modal whenever this last option is selected, like this:

```
$('#nationality_id').on('change', function() {
    if(this.value == 'new') {
        $('#nationality').modal({focus: true})
    }
});
```

The modal is just a simple Bootstrap modal with a single 'name' field:

```
<div dusk="modal-nationality" class="modal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" id="nationality">
    <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header bg-light">
                <h5 class="modal-title">Add Nationality</h5>
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                    <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                </button>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
                <div class="container-fluid">
                    <div class="form-group row">
                        <label for="name" class="col col-form-label">Nationality <span class="text-danger font-weight-bold">*</span><p class="alert-danger">{{ $errors->first('name') }}</p></label>
                        <input type="text" name="name" id="modalNationality_name" class="col form-control @error('name') is-invalid @enderror">
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                <button type="submit" id="nationality_create" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

When the form is used manually, everything works as expected, and I can add nationalities on the fly, no problem, so I created a Dusk routine to test this modal:

```
public function test_nationality_modal()
{
    $this->browse(function($browser) {
        $browser->visit('/general')
            ->select('nationality_id', 'new')
            ->whenAvailable('.modal', function ($modal) {
                $modal->assertSee('Add Nationality')
                    ->typeInDialog('name', 'my new nationality')
                   ->click('#nationality_create');
            })
            ->assertSee('my new nationality');
    });
}
```

And all I get is:

> Facebook\WebDriver\Exception\TimeoutException: Waited 5 seconds for
> selector [.modal].

I've tried using a Dusk selector such as "@nationality-modal", for example, with the same result. I've also tried $browser->waitForText(), $browser->waitForTextIn(), etc, but none of them work. I am looking at the browser while the test is running and I know for sure the option "new" (Add new option) is being selected but the modal is not displayed, so I assume the jQuery is not firing for some reason. Short of rewriting the modal scripts for the whole development, I am out of ideas, so any help would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I don't see .modal class anywhere, maybe that's the issue, try targeting .modal-body.
Have you tried ->waitForText() instead of whenAvailable(), might be more usefull.

Comment: Thanks @Toni Ilić. The main <div> that holds the modal has class="modal". I've also tried using the dusk identifier "@modal-nationality", to no avail. As I said, I did try ->waitForText(), without success. As far as I can tell, it's the jQuery that's not firing, so the modal is not being shown.